# How do I add dynamicaly added checkboxes checked items to a list?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I create Checkboxes dynamically according to a selected site. So if a site has 4 nozzles linked to it the code will create 4 checkboxes and if it has 2 it will only create 2.

I need to pull a report according to the nozzles that are check. So my idea is to add the checked item(s) to a list and then run through that list and run a query fro each id that is found. So it can pull all the records for each nozzle selected.

below is the code I use to create the nozzle checkboxes. And they are being recreated in the !ispost back method. I just don't know how to get the checked items and add them to a list. I was thinking I could either add or remove them when they are checked or unchecked or loop thorough each checkbox and add only the checked nozzles to the list.

aspx:

```
                        <tr style="color: white" id="typeNoz" visible="false" runat="server">
                            <td>Nozzle(s):
                            </td>
                            <td id="checkboxes" runat="server">
                                <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="controleplaceholder" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
```

code behind: (The lable is just for spacing)

```
        protected void Selected_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            getSiteNozzle();
        }

        void getSiteNozzle()
        {
            if (Selected.SelectedValue != "All")
            {
                if (Type.SelectedValue == "Nozzles")
                {
                    Table table = new Table();
                    table.Width = 200;
                    TableCell cell = new TableCell();
                    List<string> check = Helpers.getNozzle(Selected.SelectedValue);
                    //create a new row, cell and checkbox
                    TableRow row = new TableRow();

                    foreach (var item in check)
                    {
                        CheckBox cb = new CheckBox();
                        Label lb = new Label();
                        lb.Width = 5;
                        //set some checkbox properties
                        cb.Text = "Nozzle " + item;
                        cb.ID = "_" + item;
                        cb.TextAlign = TextAlign.Left;
                        

                        //add the checkbox to the cell
                        cell.Controls.Add(cb);
                        cell.Controls.Add(lb);

                        //the cell to the row
                        row.Controls.Add(cell);
                    }

                    //and the row to the table
                    table.Controls.Add(row);
                    //finally add the table to the page
                    controleplaceholder.Controls.Add(table);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                typeNoz.Visible = false;
            }
```

Comment: the issue is the controls you have added in the page are not maintaining viewstate

Comment: How do I make them maintain viewstate?